# Error when trying to load Excel information

Tags: c#, excel

I have C# WinForms application that gets information from Excel sheet and stores it to my database, my code works fine on my PC but when I changed it an Error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.'

display. I solved this problem by changing the project platform from x86 to x64 but when I launch the project with x64 I can't charge many files so I have to run it on x86. Guys any solutions?

Rq: My code:

```
String name = "Feuil1";
            String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                            textBox_path.Text +
                            ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$]", con);
            con.Open();

            OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataview1.DataSource = data;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UR2k_CS.Properties.Settings.StoreConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                String query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Stock (RFID,name,refrence,prix,Stockdate) VALUES (@RFID,@name,@refrence,@prix,@Stockdate)";
                connection.Open();
                        for (int i=0;i<dataview1.Rows.Count-1;i++)
                        {



                            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                            {
                                    if ((dataview1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()!=null)&&((!checkifexist(dataview1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()))) &&(dataview1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()!=""))
                                    {

                                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RFID", dataview1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", dataview1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@refrence", dataview1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prix", dataview1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());

                                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stockdate", DateTime.Now);


                                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    }       

                            }
                        }
                connection.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the 32 bit driver from here [microsoft downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255) (I think this is the correct one) but the difficulty you may run into is that a machine cannot have both the 64bit and 32bit versions installed side by side.

Using [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) is a more modern approach.